# Invalid magic cookie when connecting in mac

Tags: macos, x11, wireshark, xauth, x11-forwarding

I am trying to access a remote ubuntu server through ssh -X from mac. I enabled X11 Forwarding in the sshd_config. After connecting the ubuntu, when I try to start wireshark, I get the below error

Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyInvalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyInvalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyInvalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyError: Can't open display: localhost:10.0

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do an 'xhost +' on the host Mac (look up the man page for xhost if you want it more secure than allowing all X11 hosts to connect), then ssh -X.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I used NoMachine client to connect to the remote host. I fixed by terminating the current NoMachine session and starting a new one.